# Query returns shorter varbinary string than the actual string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

One of the tables stores long `VARBINARY(MAX)` strings to represent images.

I am trying to select images and convert them to back to images.

I noticed that the result shows a much shorter string:

```
$data = DB::select("
SELECT photo_string
FROM users_photos
WHERE user_id = 123
");

echo(strlen($data[0]->photo_string)); // shows 26633
```

But when I copy the string from the table and do `strlen()` on itm it's `53268`

The string looks like `0xFFD8FFE0......`

Why?

Comment: I know very little/nothing of the others tools you've tagged, but I suspect you are comparing the difference between something like the `binary` value `0x1234` (*a*) and `varchar` value `'0x1234'` (*b*), which have lengths of 2 and 6 respectively; *b* = *a* x 2 +2. And, unsurprisingly, 26633 x 2 + 2 = 53268.

Comment: In other words, seems that in one case you are getting the length of the binary value (26633) and in the other the length of a string value that has a binary like value (53268) in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is likely due to the way the image data is stored in the database and retrieved through your query. When storing images as VARBINARY(MAX) strings, the actual binary data of the image is converted into a series of bytes and represented as a string of characters.

When you retrieve the image data using your query, the database may be returning the encoded representation of the binary data rather than the actual binary data itself. This can result in a shorter string length compared to the original binary data.

To convert the retrieved string back into an image, you need to reverse the encoding process and convert it back into its original binary format. The specific method to accomplish this depends on the encoding mechanism used. Common encoding mechanisms for storing images as strings include Base64 encoding.

you can try this:

```
$data = DB::select("
    SELECT photo_string
    FROM users_photos
    WHERE user_id = 123
");

$encodedString = $data[0]->photo_string;
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedString);
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Hi,@DavidW, I really use chatgpt to help me every day, then I test the answer then use it

Comment: @OMR While I myself support the [responsible use of AI](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) here on SO, it's currently [not allowed](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) in any form.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds
thanks, I did not know that before, while I think tested and improved answers are totally fine even if they originally generated.
anyway, I will respect SO policy